# Spark scala dataframe get value for each row and assign to variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a dataframe like below :

val df=spark.sql("select * from table")

row1|row2|row3

A1,B1,C1

A2,B2,C2

A3,B3,C3

i want to iterate for loop to get values like this :

val value1="A1"

val value2="B1"

val value3="C1"

function(value1,value2,value3)

Please help me.

*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

- **Solution 1-** Your data is big, then you must stick with dataframes. So to apply a function on every row. We must define a UDF.
- **Solution 2-** Your data is small, then you can collect the data to the driver machine and then iterate with a map.

**Example:**

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3), (4,5,6)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
def sum(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a+b+c

// Solution 1
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val myUDF = udf((r: Row) => sum(r.getAs[Int](0), r.getAs[Int](1), r.getAs[Int](2)))

df.select(myUDF(struct($"a", $"b", $"c")).as("sum")).show

//Solution 2
df.collect.map(r=> sum(r.getAs[Int](0), r.getAs[Int](1), r.getAs[Int](2)))
```

**Output** for both cases:

```
+---+
|sum|
+---+
|  6|
| 15|
+---+
```

**EDIT:**

```
val myUDF = udf((r: Row) => {
  val value1 = r.getAs[Int](0)
  val value2 = r.getAs[Int](1)
  val value3 = r.getAs[Int](2)

  myFunction(value1, value2, value3)
})
```

Comment: I dont want to sum values

Comment: i want to get each value for each row and pass to one function

Comment: i want to collect values from one dataframe and pass to function for each row in my df

Comment: Well this is what I have done. The sum function is just an example. Replace sum by whatever you want

Comment: can you please give me example by assigning values in it

Comment: Thanks a lot  one more doubt can't we do without collect method it may occur out of memory issue for more data's

Comment: Finally you gave solution for second one i am expecting for first one

Comment: Please give me the same solution for first one

Comment: Last edit. You should have been able to do it on your own... if not please check some scala tutorial first.